# Selecting excel columns for import into python by header and NOT position

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to import certain columns of an excel sheet by the header (column title) rather than the label excel uses, such as "A" or "AA". For example, I want to upload columns 'x' and 'z' from 'df.xlsx', as created below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0,0],'y':[1,1],'z':[2,2]})
df.to_excel('df.xlsx')
```

I could do

```
from_excel = pd.read_excel('df.xlsx', usecols = 'B,D')
```

but is there a way to do this by selecting the column name, such as 'x', or 'z', rather than the excel position, e.g. 'B' or 'D'?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but the `usecols` parameter can take callables. From the docs: "New in version 0.24.0. If callable, then evaluate each column name against it and parse the column if the callable returns True.". Have you played with that at all?

Comment: What is your pandas version? This works on 0.24.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was using 0.23 but it worked on 0.24. Thanks again